# No Internet connection in VMware Player (Guest OS is Ubuntu 10.04)

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, network-adapter, vmware-player

I don't get internet connection in the guest OS. Could you please help me to find out why?
The host OS is Windows 7, guest OS is Ubuntu 10.04.

Type of network connection: NAT.

`ifconfig` command brings up the following:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:50:b9:e1  
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe50:b9e1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1628 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:150508 (150.5 KB)  TX bytes:468 (468.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:53046 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:53046 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:4657404 (4.6 MB)  TX bytes:4657404 (4.6 MB)
```

Comment: Hmmm, no IP assigned. Does W7 has network/Internet access correctly? Can you please show us the output of "route" command?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The output of route command is the following:                                                                 Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface